# String header file problems in VS2010

Tags: string.h, visual-studio-2010

When I include the header file `<string.h>` in MS Visual Studio 2010 it says nothing , but when I declare a string variable in the main function or in any function , it gives an intellisense error that says that string is an undeclared identifier

What's the solution for that issue?

Comment: Clarify please? I am assuming you are in C... so including string.h doesn't mean you get a type of "string." http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/cstring/

Comment: I'm on C 
What shall I do to use the identifier string ?

Answer (score 0):

C doesn't actually have strings, at least not really. Unlike C++, strings are actually represented as character arrays, which MUST be null terminated '\0'. What the string header actually does is define functions to help you compare, copy, and modify strings.

Valid string definitions would include:

```
char string_one[ 80 ];

char *string_two = "this is a character string";

char *string_three = malloc( 80 * sizeof( char ) );

strcpy(string_three, "I have a string now");
```

There are a TON of resources for string usage in C, heres a few to get you started:

http://www.cs.nyu.edu/courses/spring05/V22.0201-001/c_tutorial/classes/String.html

http://www.eskimo.com/~scs/cclass/notes/sx8.html

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/C_string_handling

Comment: You should also consider starting with some more basic C syntax to get the hang of it. A great reference is K&R's guide, like here: http://www.iu.hio.no/~mark/CTutorial/CTutorial.html

Comment: Want to thank you deeply for your answer 
I already work on VS , and I've been using C++ my entire life , so to write C in VS 2010 , you should choose win32 console app , and that made C & C++ mixed in my thoughts